# How to export the header of a sql statement with psql?

Tags: postgresql

How can I export the database column names as a `CSV HEADER` when exporting with `psql`?

```
psql -h database -U username - d database -t -A -F"," -f myfile.sql -o targetfile.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `-t` parameter; that means "tuples only" and add `-P footer=off` to the command line.

For more control over format, you can convert to a `COPY` command. In your .sql, something like:

```
copy (select * from foo) to stdout
with (format csv, header, delimiter ',');
```

When using this approach, you capture the output to file via redirection.

Comment: Can I prevent the `(X Lines)` statement at the end of the file when not using `-t`?

Comment: @membersound - good catch. I missed that. Edited the answer with a different approach.

Comment: How can I then use `myfile.sql` and `targetfile.csv` in the `copy with` statement? I have to supply the sql by file, and also write to file.

Comment: You can use redirection - `psql ... -f myfile.sql > targetfile.csv`. Important note that the `copy` command does support a filename (e.g., `to 'path/to/file'`) but that happens on the server, not the client. Thus, use stdout and redirection for pulling from remote servers...

Comment: I thought you would suggest using `copy... stdout with...`? I know I can use redirection `> filename` with `psql`, but how with your suggested method? Could you provide a complete example, based on my initial questions sql statement?

Comment: That's right - they work together. The SQL statement in your file is still `copy (select...) to stdout with (format csv, header, delimiter ',')`. That prints a well-formed csv to stdout. Use redirection to capture that to file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110404/discussion-between-bimsapi-and-membersound).